# Getting File Metadata from Google API in Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I am currently trying to work out how to download file meta-data from google drive using python. I have been pretty much just copying/pasting from the documentation provided by Google and have been fine up to now. When I try to call:

```
drive_file = drive_service.files().get(id=file_id).execute()
```

I receive the following error:

```
drive_file = drive_service.files().get(id=file_id).execute()
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\apiclient\discovery.py", line 452, in method
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "id"
```

However, in the google documentation there is an example [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/get#examples) (under the Python tab) that shows pretty much the exact same thing I have. Does my code not work because of my lack of Python experience or something else? Full program displayed below:

```
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

def getDriveService():
    ClientID = <MY_CLIENT_ID>
    ClientSecret = <MY_CLIENT_SECRET>
    OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    REDIRECT_URI = <MY_REDIRECT_URI>

    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(ClientID, ClientSecret, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
    flow.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    print authorize_url
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()

    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)          
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    return build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

drive_service = getDriveService()
files = drive_service.files().list().execute()

file_id = files['items'][0]['id']

#Error occurs here
drive_file = drive_service.files().get(id=file_id).execute()

print 'Title: %s' % drive_file['title']
print 'Description: %s' % drive_file['description']
print 'MIME type: %s' % drive_file['mimeType']
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with google-api, but there is a newer version of the docs that uses `get(fileId=file_id)` instead: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

Comment: Tried that, but no difference.

Answer (score 5):

I solve it.
You can modify the codes

```
drive_file=drive_service.files().get(id=file_id).execute()
```

to

```
drive_file = drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()
```